# Application crashes after Replacing fragment with custom Animation

Tags: android, animation, view, fragment, render

Within my application, I am replacing fragment with other fragment with animation. Other fragment opens perfectly but application crashed

```
java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2796)                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12648)                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)                                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)                                                                        at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1198)                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2173)                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
```

Here is my calling data :

```
frameContainer = (FrameLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.frameContainerDialog);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new FragmentConsultUserStep2(consultInfo);    
        int anim1 = R.anim.slide_in_right;
        int anim2 = R.anim.slide_out_left;
        ft.setCustomAnimations(anim1, anim2);
    ft.replace(R.id.frameContainerDialog, fragment, "FRAGMENT_STEP2");
        ft.commit();
```

My animation class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
  <!--  <alpha
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fromAlpha="loader0.loader0"
        android:toAlpha="loader1.loader0" />-->
</set>
```

Please let me know in case any one found the same issue and have resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

DetailsFragment newFragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance();

ft.replace(R.id.details_fragment_container, newFragment, "detailFragment");

// Start the animated transition.
ft.commit();
```

Comment: @Preet are you sure you're using the correct type of `FragmentManager`? Are you in an `AppCompatActivity` or other support library resource. Try `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: yes, because it was working fine. Since yesterday it is crashing , even i haven't changed anything :(

Comment: @Preet Which Fragment Manager You are Use.   You can use getSupportFragmentManager insted of getFramentManager